# End a series of `\only` with `\uncover`in beamer

Tags: beamer, conditionals, loops

In my `beamer` presentations, I often face the situation where I have a long piece of `tikz` code embedded in `\only`, in the following *schematic* structure:

```
\foreach\i in {1,...,100} {
   \only<\i>{
        [long piece of code]
   }
}
\only<101>{ some text }
```

When `some text` appears, the previous `[long piece of code]` disappears. To make it stay, I can do:

```
\foreach\i in {1,...,99} {
   \only<\i>{
        [long piece of code]
   }
}
\uncover<100-> { [long piece of code] }
\only<101> { some text }
```

but this forces me to copy the long piece of code twice, which is unelegant and unconvenient. I tried using the `\if` command:

```
 \foreach \i in {1,...,100} {
    \ifnum\i=100%
      \only<\i>%
    \else%
      \uncover<10>%
    \fi%
    {%
       [long piece of code]
    }
    \only<101>{ some text }
```

but it does produce the sought result.

How can I make a command such that it keeps only the last element?

Comment: Can't you use `\alt` to solve your issue?

Comment: @user94293 I tried `\alt<100>{\uncover<100->}{\only<\i>}{%
` but it does not do what I'd like. Is it what you were thinking about?

Comment: Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This makes it much easier for people to help you, and much more likely that they will, because they can start with your working code and modify it rather than having to spend time splicing your code snippets together to get a working example. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: If I understand what you want then your approach using `\if\i=100` will work if you replace `\uncover<10>` with `\uncover<100->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the conditional overlay specification in a macro, and then execute this macro. Below I create `\doit` to be either `\only` or `\uncover`, and then `\doit{<long piece of code>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}

  \foreach\i in {1,...,10} {
    \ifnum\i<10
      \def\doit{\only<\i>}
    \else
      \def\doit{\uncover<10->}
    \fi
    \doit{[long piece of code \i]}
  }
  \only<11>{ some text }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know why it failed in my attempt? Possibly something related to space between command and bracket?

Comment: @anderstood: This may be how the overlay specification processes its arguments. For example, under the true branch in your case, `\only<\i>` *should* be applied to `{[ long piece of code ]}`, but instead it might be applied to nothing, or `\else`, or something else altogether. In my approach, I collect the true/false branch information in `\doit`, and only execute it outside the condition.

Comment: I see. You can maybe add the following command: `\newcommand\myonly[3]{\ifnum\i<#2%
      \def\doit{\only<#1>}%
    \else%
      \def\doit{\uncover<#2->}%
    \fi%
    \doit{#3}}%` to be used as `\myonly{\i}{10}{[long piece of code]}`, tested and works. Of course the `%` have to be followed by a line break, which does not show in comments.